# How to squash commit range from root commit to a certain commit in the past non interactively?

Tags: git, rebase

If I have the following history

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G
```

A is root commit and I want to squash A-D, but keep E unchanged, I found a way to do it in 2 steps

```
git rebase --onto A C
```

then it becomes

```
A-D'-E-F-G
```

then I do a

```
git rebase -i --root
```

and in vim I interactively set D' to be `s`, then I can get what I want

```
A'-E-F-G
```

which `A'` has all the changes from A-B-C-D,  while `E` is still the original `E`( its diff does not change)

Can I do above in a simpler way ? could it be done in some magic `--onto` command in one git command ? ( non interactively) Because in the real example, I have a few hundred of commits instead of just A-B-C-D here.

Answer (score 1):

I got this answered not too long ago (like a couple of weeks ago?). It can be done like this:

```
git checkout --orphan a-new-branch D
git commit -m "Single commit for A..D"
git cherry-pick D..G
```

And you have it right there. There are other ways doing resets and stuff but I think that's simple enough.

Update:
If the history after D is complex, it might be better to run a rebase for the last step:

```
git rebase --rebase-merges D G --onto a-new-branch
```

**And** if that history is complex *and* it includes merges with conflicts, I can offer *this* script to take care of that last step to avoid having to redo the merges with conflicts:

https://github.com/eantoranz/git-replay

Comment: But I have to cherry pick F G too, what if I have a few hundred commits there instead of just E F G? I have a feeling another git rebase --onto can do it. Ah thanks did not know cherry pick can do ranges.

Comment: I had adjusted it a couple of minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all that you've written works as-is. Could you use the commit right before A for your command?

`X-A-B-C-D-E-F-G`

Given what you say, using

`git rebase --onto X C`

should give you

`X-D'-E-F-G`

Comment: I guess `A` is the first commit, that's why the OP was using `rebase --root`

Comment: Dang. Missed that bit. Thanks! I'll see for a better approach and update the answer.